# TemporaryRedirect error uploading image to AWS S3 from react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I'm getting this response back from uploading an image to AWS S3 with [react-native-aws3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3) (image is screen shot of my redux dev tools):[image]

I'm using this redux-observable epic:

```
export const uploadImageEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(UPLOAD_IMAGE)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.fromPromise(
        RNS3.put(action.payload.file, action.payload.options)
      )
        .map(response => uploadImageFulfilled(response))
        .catch(error => {
          return Observable.of(uploadImageRejected(error.xhr.response))
        })
    )
```

the action.payload.file is this (object copied from chrome console):

```
name: "image-5a430850-8314-497e-8d56-0df45e3fed95.jpg"
type: "image/png"
uri: "file:///storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.vepo/files/Pictures/image-5a430850-8314-497e-8d56-0df45e3fed95.jpg"
```

The options (object copied from chrome console):

```
accessKey: "cant really give this away"
bucket: "vepo-images"
region: "ap-southeast-2"
secretKey: "cant really give this away"
successActionStatus: 201
```

So anyway I am supposed to try again to the other endpoint. So I added this to the options object: `url: 'vepo-images.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'` and I got the exact same response back from AWS. Also tried `s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` as the url.

Any idea what I should be doing about this?

My CORS config for the bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Bucket policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1495174705604",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1495174695734",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vepo-images/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: it works now, with no changes made. Both without a `url` added to the `option` object, and with `url: 's3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`. So maybe the AWS S3 API is a bit temperamental...which could be an issue. I think i will just catch `307`'s and do a retry, toggling the `url` param in and out of the `options`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure followRedirects=true for which ever HTTP client you may be using.

Its 307 now, could be 302 later, and 301 if AWS has really gone nuts.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I can do that as I use [react-native-aws3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3) so I don't use an http client. Redirect handling could be a good feature request though.